# sync files only with same names of two folders in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I only want to sync files with same names of two folders by overwriting older files with new files in batch. Example:

in C:/folder1/

- a.txt (timestamp 1.1.2015)
- b.txt (timestamp 1.1.2015)
- c.txt

in C:/folder2/

- a.txt (timestamp 1.1.2005)
- b.txt (timestamp 1.1.2005)
- d.txt
- f.txt

After sync folder1 to folder2 I get in C:/folder2/

- a.txt (timestamp 1.1.2015)
- b.txt (timestamp 1.1.2015)
- d.txt
- f.txt

Is it possible to do that in batch? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xcopy "c:\folder1" "c:\folder2" /d /u /y
```

Where `/d` means only copy updated files, `/u` copy only files existing in target, `/y` overwrite files without confirmation

Comment: Thanks. It's so elegant. I thought it's a quite complicated problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

I got this batch from **Sachadee** and i think it would help you in your case ;)

```
:://Synchro.bat
:://SachaDee 2014
@echo off&cls
set "LesDossiers= C:\HackooTest E:\SYNCHRO\A E:\SYNCHRO\B E:\SYNCHRO\C"

for %%a in (%lesdossiers%) do (
  for %%b in (%lesdossiers%) do (
     if not "%%a"=="%%b" (
        set "VAR%%a%%b=%%a %%b")))
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims== " %%a in ('set VAR') do xcopy "%%a" "%%b" /E /D /C /Y /I
pause
```